# Cover a check box in the image to require a code for its selection

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to create something like this:

I want the check box to be hidden behind the lock image, and clicking on it will open a form requesting code entry, and if the code is correct the image will be removed and the check box will be available.

Here's what I tried:

```
[files]
Source: "Lock.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy
{...}

[code]
var
  CustomFuncPage: TWizardPage;
  CBAdvFunctions: TNewCheckBox;
  Locked: TBitmapImage;

procedure OnClickLock(Sender: TObject);
var
  PassForm: TSetupForm;
  Edit: TNewEdit;
  OKButton, CancelButton: TNewButton;
begin
  PassForm := CreateCustomForm();
  PassForm.ClientWidth := ScaleX(256);
  PassForm.ClientHeight := ScaleY(128);
  PassForm.Caption := 'Password required';

  Edit := TNewEdit.Create(PassForm);
  Edit.Top := ScaleY(10);
  Edit.Left := ScaleX(10);
  Edit.Width := PassForm.ClientWidth - ScaleX(20);
  Edit.Height := ScaleY(23);
  Edit.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
  Edit.Parent := PassForm;

  OKButton := TNewButton.Create(PassForm);
  OKButton.Parent := PassForm;
  OKButton.Caption := 'OK';
  OKButton.Left := PassForm.ClientWidth - ScaleX(166);
  OKButton.Top := PassForm.ClientHeight - ScaleY(33);
  OKButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
  OKButton.Anchors := [akRight, akBottom]
  OKButton.ModalResult := mrOk;
  OKButton.Default := True;

  CancelButton := TNewButton.Create(PassForm);
  CancelButton.Parent := PassForm;
  CancelButton.Caption := 'Cancel';
  CancelButton.Left := PassForm.ClientWidth - ScaleX(85);
  CancelButton.Top := PassForm.ClientHeight - ScaleY(33);
  CancelButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
  CancelButton.Anchors := [akRight, akBottom]
  CancelButton.ModalResult := mrCancel;
  CancelButton.Cancel := True;

  PassForm.ActiveControl := Edit;

  if PassForm.ShowModal() = mrOk then
  begin
    if Edit.Text = '1234' then
    begin
    Locked.Free;
    PassForm.Free;
    end else
    begin
    MsgBox('Password incorrect', mbError, MB_OK);
    PassForm.Free;
    end;
  end else
  begin
    PassForm.Free;
  end;
end;
  

Procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CustomFuncPage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectProgramGroup, {...}, {...});
  
  CBAdvFunctions := TNewCheckBox.Create(CustomFuncPage);
  CBAdvFunctions.Parent := CustomFuncPage.Surface;
  CBAdvFunctions.Top := 0;
  CBAdvFunctions.Left := 0;
  CBAdvFunctions.Caption := 'Advanced Functions'
  CBAdvFunctions.Width := ScaleX(130);
  CBAdvFunctions.Cursor := 1;
  CBAdvFunctions.SendToBack;

  ExtractTemporaryFile('Lock.bmp');

  Locked := TBitmapImage.Create(CustomFuncPage);
  Locked.Parent := CustomFuncPage.Surface;
  Locked.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Lock.bmp'));
  Locked.Bitmap.AlphaFormat := afPremultiplied;
  Locked.SetBounds(0, 0, CBAdvFunctions.Width, CBAdvFunctions.Height);
  Locked.Stretch := True;
  Locked.BringToFront;
  Locked.OnClick := @OnClickLock;
  {...}
```

And this is the result:

[image: lock]

This is the image I used:

[image: locked]

I tried a few ways, but was unable to get the image to cover the checkbox.

Maybe someone has an idea?

*By the way, maybe someone has an explanation for why the background of the image is not transparent?*

Comment: Ok, I believe that it's actually normal behavior in Windows. As a workaround, you can try removing the label from the checkbox and using separate `TNewStaticText`.